# Nadaraya-Watson Optimal Bandwidth

Tags: conditional-expectation, optimal, kernel-smoothing, nadaraya-watson

I am currently working on a statistical project where I need to estimate a conditional expectation $E[Y|X=x_i]$ using the Nadaraya-Watson estimator. For doing that, I have the sample $(x_1,y_1),...,(x_n,y_n)$, where $n=14$, and I have chosen the bandwidth $h$ such that : $h = n^{-\frac{1}{5}}=0.5899$, given that the common rule of thumb is to have $h \propto n^{-\frac{1}{5}}$ for optimality.

However, I do not get in what sense that $h$ is optimal. Indeed, I am using R, the `ksmooth` function with a `normal` kernel : `ksmooth(X,Y,"normal",bandwidth=h)`.This is what I get if I choose such a $h$:

[image]

While if for example I choose $h$ equal to 3 (so around 5 times bigger), I get a way smoother curve, which is what really interests me:

[image]

Could someone explain me in what sense having $h \propto n^{-\frac{1}{5}}$ is "optimal"?

What am I sacrificing if I choose a $h$ bigger than the "optimal" one: accuracy, convergence speed, etc.?

I greatly appreciate, thank you very much.

Comment: P.S. this is the second message I post in which my beginning "Hello everyone" is erased, does somebody know why? I wouldn't like to seem rude.

Comment: Well, according to Bochner-Landau notation, both are equivalent big-O. In any case, you should not be computing the bandwidth by hand, but using a rule like Rupert-Sheather-Wand implemented in the `KernSmooth` package.

Comment: Sorry T C, I don't get it, what is equivalent to what? The function you refer to from the `KernSmooth` package is `dpill`? The issue here is that my priority is smoothness, and if an optimal bandwidth yields a graph like the 1st one I posted above it is useless, that is why I was asking what do I sacrifice when I increase the bandwidth with respect to some optimal value.

Comment: 5*0.5899 is the same as 0.5899. Please post your data in order to show the performance of different theoretically motivated bandwidth selection rules.

Comment: The "Hellos" "Thanks!"es and "Appologies if..." do not contribute to, and in fact distract from questions and answers. Remember your questions here, and responses to them are a collaborative community legacy, not simply a conversation you are having on your own. So those social niceties that work well on, say, social networking sites and forums are inappropriate here.

Comment: Oh, I though that 3 was an order higher than 0.5899 @T C. For the moment, after observing the poor results I got with 0.5899, I just tried different (higher) values for h. Thank you for the clarification @Alexis

Answer (score 3):

It's optimal in that it minimized the mean (integrated) squared error for a data generating process as a function of some parameters and the sample size. The trick is that "proportional to" means there's an unknown factor multiplying $n^{-\frac{1}{5}}$.

There are various candidates that are more or less data-driven, but the simplest RoT bandwidth when using a second order kernel is $$h=\sigma_x \cdot n^{-\frac{1}{5}}.$$

See [Li and Racine, *Nonparametric Econometrics:
Theory and Practice*](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8355.html), bottom of [p.66](http://books.google.com/books?id=Zsa7ofamTIUC&lpg=PT100&vq=rule-of-thumb%20procedure&pg=PT101#v=onepage&q&f=false). Usually, one can do much better than this by using CV to pick $h$ instead.

Comment: Ok, thank you @Dimitriy V. Masterov, just a clarification, the standard deviation in your comment is the one from my data?

Comment: Well thank you, I've checked this and the result is way better, in fact the standard deviation times n to the power of -1/5 yields 3.0965 so the curve is quite smooth.

Comment: @JJFM Yes, I added a link to GB with the text.

Comment: This is an excellent textbook.